# Understanding SARIMAX Model's Graph: A Comprehensive Guide

Tags: sarimax

I am stuck with this graph and outcome. Would any kind soul help me explaining this graph and statistical figure. so that I can input more info in finding.

another does the exogenous variable always use last 21 values of the dataset?